# Get info about resources consumed by thread in runtime

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've got a .NET multithreaded application. Is there any way to display information about resources consumed by the thread like CPU,Mememory e.t.c in runtime?
For example if I've go a thread running a heavy math operation with large memory use I would like to know how mush that particular thread consumes.

Comment: You can use [Diagnostic Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: They are also accessable via C# in runtime?

Comment: hmmm i don't think you can show up memory consumtion of a thread. For example: You could use a thread to initialize a big data set. After the data is initialized the thread could be terminated but the objects are still allocated....

Answer (score 0):

This is going to give you the whole process memory usage:

```
// get the current process
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

// get the physical mem usage
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```

Per thread measurements, I suggest you keep track of the number of used objects (not a trivial task though).

Answer (score 0):

A central concept of a thread is that it shares its owning processes resources.  Threads don't have a concept of resource ownership of their own.

If you are wanting a view of the process (and contained threads) from outside, there are a number of tools available.

If you are wanting to keep track of usage for dynamic allocation; first make sure you really need to (.net manages memory very well).  But, if the need is there, the [`System.Diagnostics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace is where you will want to look; particularly at the `PerformanceCounters`.  But keep in mind that active monitoring will change the performance characteristics.